# how to post two select box values to php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two select box in a form. Filter out the selected values output from database. Here My code

html code

```
              <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" style="width:100px; height:30px;">
              <input type="date" name="date" id="date_id" style="width:150px; height:30px; margin-top:-29px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px;">

              <select name="value1" style="width:51px; height:30px;margin-left:161px; margin-top:-29px; margin-bottom:0px;">
              <option value="asc">ASC</option>
              <option value="dsc">DSC</option>
              </select>
              <select name="value2" style="width:149px; height:30px;margin-left:226px; margin-top:-26px;">
              <option value="readytoship">Ready To Ship</option>
              <option value="readytodispatch">Ready To Dispatch</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="submit" style="margin-left:163px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:0px;"/>
              </form>
```

php code:

```
              <?php
              include "db.php";
              if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {
                        if(($_POST['value1'] == 'asc') && ($_POST['value2'] == 'readytoship'))
                        {
                            // query to get all Fitzgerald records
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM purna_orders WHERE shipping_status='readytoship' order by po_created_date asc";
                        }
                        elseif(($_POST['value1'] == 'dsc') && ($_POST['value2'] == 'readytoship'))
                        {
                            // query to get all Herring records
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM purna_orders WHERE shipping_status='readytoship' order by po_created_date dsc";
                        } 
                        elseif(($_POST['value1'] == 'asc') && ($_POST['value2'] == 'readytodispatch'))
                        {
                            // query to get all Herring records
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM purna_orders WHERE shipping_status='readytodispatch' order by po_created_date asc";
                        }
                        elseif(($_POST['value1'] == 'dsc') && ($_POST['value2'] == 'readytodispatch'))
                        {
                            // query to get all Herring records
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM purna_orders WHERE shipping_status='readytodispatch' order by po_created_date dsc";
                        }
                        else {
                            // query to get all records
                            $query = "select * from purna_orders where shipping_status='readytoship' order by po_created_date asc ";
                        }
                        $query = "select * from purna_orders where shipping_status='readytoship' order by po_created_date asc ";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);

                        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                        if($num_rows >= 1)
                            {

                            echo "<div id='showmenu' class='scroll'>";  

                        echo "<table id='table_struct' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' width='400' height='30'>
                             <tr class='tr_class' bgcolor='white'>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Select </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Order Id </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Customer Name </td>

                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Price </td>

                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Pincode </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> COD </td>
                             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Status </td>
                        </tr>";
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                    $po_id = $row['po_id'];
                                    $_SESSION['po_id'] = $po_id;
                                    $is_cod =($row['is_cod'])? 'Yes' : ' ';
                                    echo "<tr height='20' data-order_id='".$row['po_id']."'>
                                    <td align='center'><input type='radio' class='case' name='case' value='1'></td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['po_id']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['customer_name']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['order_value']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['bill_to_pincode']."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$is_cod."</td>
                                    <td align='center'>".$row['shipping_status']."</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                                    }

                                    echo "</table>";

                                    echo "</div>";
                                    }
                        }

                        ?>
```

Problem is its directly executing the else part not checking the conditions.

And i need to display all the records from database defaultly without clicking filter.

Comment: use echo var_dump($_POST), to check post data, then proceed.

Comment: your code is working for me. it goes to correct condition?

Comment: why you write an extra query out of all if else conditions. that have any mean? i don't think it have any mean? it overrides your query what you write in if else condition

Comment: sry by mistake i coded it

Answer (score 3):

You code isn't checking if it has null value. So check this way and perform action.

```
if(!empty($_POST[`value1`]) && !empty($_POST[`value2`])) {
    //write code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your PHP code to this

```
       $shipping_status = 'readytoship';
       $order = 'ASC';
       if (!empty($_POST[`value1`]) {
          $shipping_status = $_POST[`value1`];
       }
       if (!empty($_POST[`value2`]) {
          $order = $_POST[`value2`];
       }
      $query = 'select * from purna_orders where shipping_status="'.$shipping_status.'" order by po_created_date "'.$order.'"';
      //other stuff
```

and html to this

```
<select name="value1" style="width:51px; height:30px;margin-left:161px; margin-top:-29px; margin-bottom:0px;">
              <option value="asc">ASC</option>
              <option value="desc">DSC</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: how its check the each value in dropdown if i give like dis??

Comment: I have edited my answer, check if understand the code what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this

```
if($_POST[`value1`] != "") && ($_POST[`value2`] != "")) {
    //Something your query should be here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your query outside your if else condition

```
$query = "select * from purna_orders where shipping_status='readytoship' order by po_created_date asc ";
```

Remove this it should work